# C++11 lambda ambigious

Tags: c++, c++11

Why can the compiler not select the most obvious overload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

static void foo(const std::function<void(bool)>& f) {
    std::cerr << "using bool overload" << std::endl;
    f(true);
}

static void foo(const std::function<void(int)>& f) {
    std::cerr << "using int overload" << std::endl;
    f(1);
}

int main() {
    foo([](const bool value) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << std::endl;
    });
    foo([](const int value) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

You would expect the output:

```
using bool overload
true
using int overload
1
```

However, the compiler cannot deduce the correct overload:

`gcc-4.8`:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:6: error: call of overloaded 'foo(main()::__lambda0)' is ambiguous
     });
      ^
main.cpp:17:6: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:4:13: note: void foo(const std::function<void(bool)>&)
 static void foo(const std::function<void(bool)>& f) {
             ^
main.cpp:9:13: note: void foo(const std::function<void(int)>&)
 static void foo(const std::function<void(int)>& f) {
             ^
```

`clang-3.4`:

```
main.cpp:15:5: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    foo([](const bool value) {
    ^~~
main.cpp:4:13: note: candidate function
static void foo(const std::function<void(bool)>& f) {
            ^
main.cpp:9:13: note: candidate function
static void foo(const std::function<void(int)>& f) {
            ^
```

Is this because the `std::function` constructor automatically consumes and converts parameters?

Comment: "Is this because the std::function constructor automatically consumes and converts parameters?" `std::function` has a very greedy ctor template. Also, as there's a conversion from `bool` to `int` (and vice versa), both functions can be called with arguments of both types (that's why the conversion isn't refused for one of the overloads).

Comment: Can I write a overload that accepts lambdas/functors in a way that the overload correctly works? Edit: or write a `type_trait` that gets the parameter type?

Comment: Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/854d7be9aeb9b00b)? (The implicit conversions inherited from C are often evil ;)

Comment: That works because the types are implicitly convertible to each other so the function ctor cannot convert, right? I really need it to work with the primitive types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isn't the template argument (the signature) of std::function part of its type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931214/isnt-the-template-argument-the-signature-of-stdfunction-part-of-its-type)

Comment: Note that even with the fix mentioned in the answers on the duped question, your example wouldn't work because `int` and `bool` are convertible to each other.

Comment: That works because the types are **not** implicitly convertible to each other, yes ;) If you can change the signature of `foo`, I'd make it a template (so that the lambda-expression doesn't need to be wrapped in `std::function`) and either use tag-dispatch or specialization (on an *additional* template parameter) to provide different functionality for different "argument types".

Comment: @Xeo, I guess I should clarify the situation: all I need to know is the type of the first argument to the overload. Working out the answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667449)

Comment: @Xeo: I agree that the possible duplicate question is very relevant to this one but it's not really a duplicate. (Exactly because of you said on `int` and `bool` being convertible to each other.) In addition, the code in the old question compiles fine with gcc 4.8.1. So I guess, there was a bug in gcc/libstdc++ that has been fixed since then. (I haven't tried other compilers though.)

Comment: @Cassio: It was not a bug, the standard specifies `std::function`'s constructor like that. Post-C++11 there's a DR with a proposed fix that makes the original code in the duped question unambiguous. Also, note that this question only asks of the cause, not of the fix. That should be a seperate question (and likely also a duplicate).

Comment: From cppreference: "The lambda expression constructs an unnamed temporary object of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate type, known as closure type ... ". This seems to be the key to the problem ;)

Comment: @Xeo Agreed (thanks). For the record this is the [DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2132) that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to find the type of the lambda, this worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename F>
struct first_argument {
  template<typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
  static A  helper(Ret (F::*)(A, Rest...));
  template<typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
  static A helper(Ret (F::*)(A, Rest...) const);
  typedef decltype(helper(&F::operator())) type;
};

template <typename T>
static void foo(T f) {
    typedef typename first_argument<T>::type type;
    std::cerr << "using traits overload" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "typename: " << typeid(type).name() << std::endl;
    f(true);
}

template<typename T>
static void foo(void (*f)(const T)) {
    std::cerr << "using function pointer overload" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "typename: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    f(T());
}


int main() {
    const bool x = false;
    foo([](const bool value) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << std::endl;
    });
    const int i = 9;
    foo([i](const bool value) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << ':' << i << std::endl;
    });
    foo(+[](const bool value) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << std::endl;
    });
    foo(+[](const int value) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    });
    foo([&x](const bool value) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << value << '|' << x << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Run it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44980f0c19539e8b)

Comment: This only works for non-capturing lambda's. Lambda's that capture _anything_, even a simple `int` cannot be converted to function pointers.

Comment: @MSalters, huh? It works fine.  Have updated the answer. It _doesn't_ work with `std::bind` though and fails when used as a template trait type.

Comment: The influx of this kind of questions is driving me insane NIPPLE SALADS! but I think "finding the type of the lambda" is the wrong problem :< (Note how I said wrong *problem*; I don't even want to look at the solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda's may have a funky syntax, but they're still functors. That is to say, they define an `unique_type::operator()(Args...)`. This is also true for capturing lambda's; the captured values are members of the lambda object.

So, the following bit of code breaks down a lambda object:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename A>
void bar(T const& t, R (T::*pmf)(A));

template<typename LAMBDA>
void foo(LAMBDA const& l)
{
  bar(l, &LAMBDA::operator());
}
```

Obviously, if you just need to distinguish between the two lambda's in your example, you can replace `bar` with two non-templatized functions. OTOH, if you need to support lambda's with any number of arguments, you'll need a variadic template for `bar`.