# Getting parameter type of function with templates

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have a function with the following signature:

```cpp
void foo(std::string const& a, int b, char &c) {
    ...
}
```

How could I do something like `param_type<foo, 3>::type` to get type == char?

Background:

I have a set of macros/TMP which generates a struct for converting a json object into a c++ value. I also have a set of structs representing each of the json types (primitives, array, object, etc). The main struct is defined by an X-macro, and the implementer must pass the parameter type (also used as the field type), the json type (one of the structs), and the key name into the X macros to define the fields.

I want to be able to separate the field type from the parameter type, so I can have something like `std::optional<TField>` as the struct's field type and TField passed to the parse method. These macros are being used in many places, so I don't want to add another parameter to the X macros.

I tried using an `auto` variable but as far as I know, something like the following isn't possible, which is why I want `param_type`.

```cpp
auto value;
parse(..., value);
field = value;
```

Comment: `param_type<foo, 3>::type` would be ambiguous if that function were overloaded, correct?  Are you assuming there is only one `foo` in existance?

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, I'm assuming there will only ever be one overload for the function, and that whatever is passed to `param_type` will be convertable to a function pointer, and well defined. It'll only ever be passed a static class method that's in the current assembly/object (defined in the header it's declared in).

Comment: I don't get the idea. What does this deserialization has to do with getting i-th function parameter? Also I don't understand why specify a json type for every field manually. Can't you deduce it automatically from the C++ field type (or rather, just have something like `deserialize(T &, const Json &)` specialized/overloaded for each supported type).

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6512019/509868).

Comment: You basically want function traits. Boost already has them and the interface is just like you wanted - you pass function type as the template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function traits with partial specialization:

```
template <auto func, std::size_t I>
struct param_type;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret (*func)(Args...), std::size_t I>
struct param_type<func, I>
{
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Args...>>;
};

// C-ellipsis version aka printf-like functions
template <typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret (*func)(Args..., ...), std::size_t I>
struct param_type<func, I>
{
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Args...>>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/66novvM4M)

Answer (score 1):

Another `std::tuple_element` way pass through a function declaration (only declaration, no definition required)

```
template <std::size_t Ind, typename R, typename ... Args>
std::tuple_element_t<Ind-1u, std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>>
   pt_helper (R(Args...));
```

so `param_type` simply become

```
template <auto X, std::size_t Ind>
struct param_type
 { using type = decltype( pt_helper<Ind>(X) ); };
```

Observe the `Ind-1u` in the `pt_helper` declaration: you asked that `param_type` return the third argument type of the function with argument `3`: usually, in C/C++ world, the index are counted from zero. I suggest that you accept that `param_type<foo, 2>::type` is `char`; in that case you have to remove the `-1`.

Observe also the `std::remove_reference_t`. Is required because you want that `param_type<foo, 3>::type` is `char` (without reference) and not `char &` (with reference).

Anyway, the following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

void foo (std::string const& a, int b, char &c)
 { }

template <std::size_t Ind, typename R, typename ... Args>
std::tuple_element_t<Ind-1u, std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>>
   pt_helper (R(Args...));


template <auto X, std::size_t Ind>
struct param_type
 { using type = decltype( pt_helper<Ind>(X) ); };


int main ()
 {
   using T = typename param_type<foo, 3u>::type;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T, char>, "!" );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if 2 types are the same with `std::is_same<T,U>::value` in this case

```
if (std::is_same<param_type<foo, 3>::type,char>::value) {
    /*stuff*/
}else {
    /*stuff2*/
}
```

See more about [is_same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party but see my own complete (free) function traits library [here](https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits) (production grade, full-documented - much smaller and more complete than the Boost version). Applying it to your code (demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/d7Ya14YG8)):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// See https://github.com/HexadigmSystems/FunctionTraits
#include "TypeTraits.h"

void foo(std::string const& a, int b, char &c)
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Everything in "TypeTraits.h" above declared
    // in this namespace
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    using namespace StdExt;
    
    using F = decltype(foo);
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 3rd type in "foo()" (passing 2 as the zero-based index)
    // so yields "char &" (the arg's exact type). Just apply
    // "std::remove_reference_t" as well if you want to remove
    // the "&" (resulting in "char").
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    using Arg3InFoo_t = ArgType_t<F, 2>;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Display above type (its user-friendly name). Alternatively you
    // can use "ArgTypeName_v" instead of "TypeName_v" (former just
    // defers to the latter).
    //
    // Note: Following call to "tcout" (also declared in "TypeTraits.h"
    // above) always resolves to "std::cout" on non-Microsoft platforms
    // and usually "std::wcout" on Microsoft platforms (when compiling
    // for UTF-16 in that environment which is usually the case). You
    // can directly call "std::cout" or "std::wcout" instead if you
    // prefer, assuming you know which platform you're always running
    // on.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    tcout << TypeName_v<Arg3InFoo_t>;
    
    return 0;
}
```